# HashiCorp Vault - Amalgamating multiple aliases under a single entity after login via multiple OIDC auth methods and user ids

Tags: azure-active-directory, ldap, openid-connect, alias, hashicorp-vault

We're trying to implement OIDC single sign-on to our HashiCorp Vault instance, through the following multiple auth methods:

1. Azure AD (user authentication is through the individual's corporate email address)
2. LDAP (user authentication is through a unique corporate personal identification number)

Each user within the organisation will have an account in both Azure and LDAP and so to avoid a single user being registered under two separate Vault entities (thereby taking up 2 Vault licences), it is imperative that we device a mechanism where the two designated Vault aliases for Azure AD and LDAP are amalgamated under one single Vault entity.

At the moment this is proving a challenge, due to the fact both auth methods used in our OIDC single sign-on implementation, rely on two entirely different identifiers for authentication:

- a user email, and
- a personal id number

As such, if say Joe Bloggs logged into our Vault instance using `joebloggs@my-org.com` (**Azure AD**) and `joebloggs12345` (**LDAP**), Vault has no way of identifying them both as the same individual, in order to create both aliases under a single entity.

Any idea how we could automate the amalgamation of the two Vault auth method aliases under one entity?

Answer (score 0):

From the Microsoft side **you might try using [Azure AD B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/overview) as an IdP for Vault**. Both [OIDC providers (AAD and LDAP)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-identity-provider) would be federated trough B2C.

Other options to federate both OIDC providers would be [Identity Server](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/#) and [KeyCloack](https://www.keycloak.org/).

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but I'm afraid none of them will be of much use in our scenario. Please note that we're not looking to leverage the usage of a new OIDC provider including B2C. Our two (Azure AD and LDPA) are currently in use and set in stone and the eventual SSO solution with Vault has to be formulated around these two only.

Comment: Unless Vault supports multiple identities for its users, I'm afraid you will require an additional or custom IdP.